# How to use teacher forcing in training model using LSTM for time-series problem

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am new to ML. I searched a lot about using teacher forcing in LSTM. Without teacher forcing LSTM works well for time series problem but it does not predict well for future sample.

Can somebody help on this please.

Comment: Does anybody knows about it.

Comment: Your question is not well-posed. Why don't you just try it on your problem and see if it helps?